# Share script with non coders

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote some script with tkinter as a GUI and pyinstaller to convert it to an exe.

1. However gmail doesn’t allow me to share the file
2. if I share the file with google drive then windows security gets triggered

What’s a good safe and easy way for people who don’t know how to install python to use the code I write in python.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use Discord. I believe you can upload an exe to Discord.